# gdb set disassembly-flavor intel on armv7

Tags: gdb, arm

im debugging on armv7 platform and i need to see the disass of a function ( in C ).
i'm using gdb 7.3 but there isn't disass-flavor option.
how i can see the disassembled code in intel flavor?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Did Intel publish ARM assembly code in a different syntax from ARM's own? GDB uses the same syntax as gas, which should be the same syntax as ARM's native documentation and tools.

Comment: intel vs at&t have to do with 80x86 assembler.  ARM is a different processor has nothing to do with it and the assembler has not been hijacked like x86 has.  Likewise avr assembler doesnt have intel format vs at&t, nor 6502, nor mips, etc.  Only intel 80x86.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
now I've understood. thanks! :)